# NeoVim terminal support

Tags: neovim

This is my config init.vim : https://github.com/NeuralNine/config-files/blob/master/init.vim

when i do `:TerminalSplit bash` i get the terminal in this process which works fine.
[image]

but when i do `:TerminalSplit bash` on this process terminal just looks empty and not working fine, why is that ?
[image: but when i do :TerminalSplit bash on this process terminal just looks empty]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

You'd need to create an issue on [`vim-terminal`](https://github.com/tc50cal/vim-terminal) for that but it looks like that this plugin isn't maintained anymore since the last commit is 4 years ago.

### Alternative fix

Anyway as an alternativ you can try to use the builtin `:terminal` command which can open up a terminal for you as well. Here's a little mapping which you can use:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-t> :vsplit <bar> :term<CR>
```

This will create a new window on the right and starts a new shell for you. You can also add the following snippet to your `init.vim`:

```
augroup TerminalSplitup
    autocmd!
    autocmd TermOpen * setlocal list
    autocmd TermOpen,TermEnter * startinsert
augroup END
```

which should bring you automatically into insert mode if you open up that terminal-window.

Also another hint:

```
tnoremap <silent> <Esc> <C-\><C-n>
```

use this mapping if you want to be able to scroll through your terminal. This mapping will let you leave the insert mode in your terminal to be able to scroll through the terminal-buffer with the normal vim-keybindings.